# Does there exist an injective Lipschitz map on the disk whose gradient switches between two given matrices?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

While solving a problem in calculus of variations, I came to the following question:

Let $A,B$ be two real $2 \times 2$ matrices with positive determinants, and suppose that $\operatorname{rank}(A-B)=1$.

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the closed unit disk.
Does there exist a Lipschitz map $u:D 
\to D$  such that:

1. $\nabla u \in \{A,B\}$ a.e. in $D$
2. $u$ is surjective.
3. $u^{-1}(y)$ is a singleton for almost every $y \in D$.

---

By a theorem by Ball and James, any $u$ satisfying condition $(1)$ is of the following form:

Write $B-A=an^T$ for some $a,n \in\mathbb{R}^2$, $n$ a unit vector. Then
$$
u(x)=Ax+h(x\cdot n)a+v_0,
$$
for some $v_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and a Lipschitz function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h' \in \{0,1\}$ a.e..

So, it "remains" to examine maps $u$ of the form above.

---

The assumptions $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that the average integral of the Jacobian $Ju$ is $1$, so the measure of the set where $\nabla u=A$ is predetermined by $\det A,\det B$.

---

If it matters, then in my case of application, $A \in \alpha \text{SO}(2)$, where $\alpha>1$, and the singular values of $B$ satisfy:
$\sigma_1+\sigma_2>\beta>1$ and $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 <<1$ very close to zero. Here $\alpha, \beta$ are some fixed parameters.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I do not have time to complete details. I still believe my answer is correct. If I can complete details I will undelete it.